# Splitting of varchar column using the special character

Tags: sql-server

I have a column which values will be

```
1_987123
12_987654
```

Here, I need to separate only the first letter that is `'1'` and `'12'` in the column values. I have tried `substring` and `charindex` to find the value. The syntax I have used is:
`substring(Columnname,1,charindex('_',Columnname,1)-1)`.

This works to find for the column which have values. But in my case we have blank values in the column. In that case the above syntax is giving error. Tried the scenarios like `coalesce` and its not accepting as the column data type is `varchar`.

Can you please suggest me some other option?

Comment: You want to get the first number before the underscore isn't it. For example 1_987123,12_987654. You need 1,12.

Comment: what do you want as result if the column is missing underscore but still contains a value - blank or the value ? My answer returns blank since I consider it incorrect data, but only guessing

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `CASE` expression to handle values without `'_'`:

```
WITH Tbl(col) AS(
    SELECT '1_987123' UNION ALL
    SELECT '12_987654' UNION ALL
    SELECT '12'
)
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('_', col) > 0 THEN LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('_', col)-1)
        ELSE col
    END
FROM Tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, It supports null values, values without underscore and empty strings values in your columns.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN charindex('_', COL) > 0
            THEN substring(col, 1, charindex('_', COL) - 1)
        ELSE col
        END
FROM (
    VALUES ('1_987123')
        ,('12_987654')
        ,('12')
        ,(NULL)
        ,('')
    ) T(COL)
```

Use filter like this,

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN charindex('_', COL) > 0
            THEN substring(col, 1, charindex('_', COL) - 1)
        ELSE col
        END
FROM (
    VALUES ('1_987123')
        ,('12_987654')
        ,('12')
        ,(NULL)
        ,('')
        ,('3_545')
        ,('3')
    ) T(COL)
    where col like '3%'
```

Comment: I would like to use the above syntax in where condition. Ex: select * from table_name where substring(Columnname,1,charindex('_',Columnname,1)-1) = '3'; Please suggest some option for this.

Answer (score 1):

or you can cheat a bit by apending the underscore at the back

```
SELECT LEFT (col, CHARINDEX('_', col + '_') - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can use, start at position 0 instead of position 1 and do not subtract 1. This will return empty string when there is no underscore.

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(Columnname,0,charindex('_',Columnname,1))
FROM (values('1_987123'),('7123'),('12_987654')) x(columnname)
```

Result:

```
1

12
```